# Is there a way to convert this json file?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have this json file:

```
{
  "spain" : "spanish.",
  "usa" : "english",
  "france" : "french",
  "italy" : "italian",
  ...
}
```

Is there a fast way to convert that json file in this below?

```
[ 
 { "country": "spain", "language": "spanish." }
 { "country": "usa", "language": "english." }
 { "country": "france", "language": "french." }
 { "country": "italy", "language": "italian." }
  ...
}
```

Comment: In which language? Python or JS?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Forget about the JSON part and pretend you have a dict hardcoded in your source code, and you want to generate the list of dicts and just print it out. Can you do that? (Then it's just a matter of adding a `json.loads` at the start and a `json.dumps` at the end, or the equivalent `JSON` methods in JS.)

Comment: @Teemu I prefer javascript, but python would be good as well ;)

Comment: What is the hard part? Getting the JSON from the file? Converting it to an object? Reconstructing the object? Something else?

Comment: the hard part is converting this "spain" : "spanish.", to this { "country": "spain", "language": "spanish." }

Comment: Here's a hint (for Python): `for country, language in d.items():` will do exactly what you'd hope it will, so you just need to figure out how to make the dictionary `{'country': country, 'language': language}` and add it to the output list.

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript**

Using the function `map`.

```js
var countries = { "spain" : "spanish", "usa" : "english", "france" : "french", "italy" : "italian"  }
    result = Object.entries(countries).map(([c, l]) => ({country: c, language: l}));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python with list comprehension:

```
import json
with open("test.json", 'r') as f:
    test = json.load(f)
json.dumps([{"country": key, "language": test[key]} for key in test.keys()])
```

Answer (score 2):

JS: Iterate through the keys of input object, assign each key to output object's country field and corresponding value to its language field.

```js
var input = {"spain":"spanish"};
var output = [];
Object.keys(input).forEach((key, ind) => 
    { 
        output.push({country: key, language:input[key]}); 
    });
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the JSON part for now. The hard part here is turning each of those `'spain': 'spanish'` key-value pairs into separate dicts, right?

First, consider this:

```
for country, language in d.items():
```

This gives you a loop, where each time through the loop, you get one of those key-value pairs, like `country = 'spain'` and `language = 'spanish'`. So, all you have to do is create your desired-format dictionary, and append it to some results.

Get that working for converting a dict hardcoded into your source and printing out the list at the end.

Once you've finished and debugged that, it's a simple matter of `json.loads` instead of a hardcoded dict, and `json.dumps` instead of `print`. Or, if you want this to load and save files instead of filtering stdin to stdout, `open` the filenames and then use `json.load` and `json.dump` on the resulting file instead.

If you get stuck on any of those parts, you'll have a great, specific question to ask on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
In[2]: import json
  ...: 
  ...: result = []
  ...: with open('hmm.json', 'r') as f:
  ...:     json_dict = json.load(f)
  ...:     for country, language in json_dict.items():
  ...:         result.append({
  ...:             'country': country,
  ...:             'language': language
  ...:         })
  ...: 
In[3]: result
Out[3]: 
[{'country': 'spain', 'language': 'spanish.'},
 {'country': 'usa', 'language': 'english'},
 {'country': 'france', 'language': 'french'},
 {'country': 'italy', 'language': 'italian'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var arr = [];
var keys = Object.keys(myobj);
for(var i in keys){
    var key = keys[i];
    if(key){
        arr.push({"country":key,"language":myobj[key]});
    }
}
```